# Postgres SETOF to Array without a subquery

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a generated column in postgres with the following "as" statement:

```
array_to_string(
  array(
    select lpad(regexp_split_to_table(label, E'\\.+'), 5, '0')
  ),
  ''
);
```

However it fails because `cannot use subquery in column generation expression`. So my question is can that be done without having the nested select to convert the lpad's set of to an array?

Thanks

Comment: Create stored function that wraps the expression.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample data from the `label` column and how those values should look like in the generated column.

Comment: @Abelisto thanks that worked - the function I created needed to be immutable.